Why $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x+x^2e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{xe^{-nx}+x^2}{1+e^{-nx}}$?
Here is a question:

When $x > 0$, find $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x+x^2e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}}$

The solution process in the answer is:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x+x^2e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{xe^{-nx}+x^2}{1+e^{-nx}} = \frac{0+x^2}{1+0} = x^2 $$
I don't understand why $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x+x^2e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{xe^{-nx}+x^2}{1+e^{-nx}} $$

Muitiply numerator an denominator by $e^{-nx}$.

Factorise both numerator and denominator:
$$ \frac{x+x^2e^{nx}}{1+e^{nx}} =\frac{e^{nx}(xe^{-nx} + x^2)}{e^{nx}(e^{-nx}+1)} .$$

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x + x^2 e^{nx}}{1 + e^{nx}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x e^{-nx} + x^2}{1 + e^{-nx}} $
it is true here because both sides are tending  to $ x^{2}$ as $ n \to \infty $. In L.H.S  the exponential growth of $ e^{nx} $ to $x^{2}$ and in the R.H.S, $ e^{-nx} $ tend to 0 , making the numerator  $ x^2$ and denominator to 1 .
SO , L.H.S=R.H.S.
that is why this equality holds.
